# Foxpro failing to connect to ODBC, showing dialogue box

Tags: foxpro

I am working on a Foxpro 9 program. I have a function to connect to Excel and bring back the column information. Running in Foxpro, this works as expected. However, when running a built executable, a Windows 'Select Data Source' dialogue box is displayed, offering File or Machine data source options. Choosing the right one doesn't work either, but in any case I don't want the dialogue.

This is running in 64bit Windows 8, but I have also tested in 32 bit. The program file with the Excel functions is built into the executable. Can anyone tell me why the built program is running differently?

```
RELEASE aCols
DIMENSION aCols(1)
AWorkSheetColumns(@aCols, m.tmpFile, m.tmpSheet, "DSN=Microsoft Excel Driver")

**********************************
FUNCTION AWorkSheetColumns(taArray, tcXLSFile, tcSheet, tnDSN)
**********************************
**********************************
* PARAMETER Information
* taArray := an array sent in by reference to fill with the specified worksheet's column information
* tcXLSFile := a string specifying an excel file (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb) on disk
* tcSheet := a string specifying the worksheet or table to use when retrieving column information
*
* RETURN Information
* returns numeric, the number of columns found in the worksheet/table
**********************************
LOCAL lnSQL, laErr[1], lnResult, lnReturn, lcSQLAlias, loExc
m.lnReturn = 0
IF !EMPTY(m.tnDSN)
    m.lnSQL = SQLSTRINGCONNECT(m.tnDSN+ ";" ;
        +"DBQ="+FULLPATH(m.tcXLSFile)+";")
ELSE
    m.lnSQL = SQLSTRINGCONNECT("Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" ;
        +"DBQ="+FULLPATH(m.tcXLSFile)+";")
ENDIF
*!* Alternate using DSN that comes with Office install (MSDASQL = OLEDB wrapper for ODBC)
*!*     m.lnSQL = SQLSTRINGCONNECT("Provider=MSDASQL.1;" ;
*!*         +"Persist Security Info=False;" ;
*!*         +"DSN=Excel Files;" ;
*!*         +"DBQ="+FULLPATH(m.tcXLSFile)+";" ;
*!*         +"DriverId=790;" ;
*!*         +"MaxBufferSize=2048;" ;
*!*         +"PageTimeout=5;")

*!* Try a few other drivers that may be on the user's machine
IF m.lnSQL < 0
    IF UPPER(ALLTRIM(JUSTEXT(m.tcXLSFile))) == "XLS" && can we try using the older driver?
        m.lnSQL = SQLSTRINGCONNECT("Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" ;
            + "DBQ="+FULLPATH(m.tcXLSFile)+";")
        IF m.lnSQL < 0
            m.lnSQL = SQLSTRINGCONNECT("Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};" ;
                + "DBQ="+FULLPATH(m.tcXLSFile)+";")
        ENDIF
    ELSE
        m.lnSQL = SQLSTRINGCONNECT("Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" ;
            + "DBQ="+FULLPATH(m.tcXLSFile)+";")
    ENDIF
    IF m.lnSQL < 0
        AERROR(m.laErr)
        ERROR m.laErr[2]
    ENDIF
ENDIF

m.lcSQLAlias = SYS(2015)
m.lnResult = SQLEXEC(m.lnSQL,[SELECT * FROM "] + m.tcSheet + [$" Where 1=0], m.lcSQLAlias)

IF m.lnSQL > 0
    SQLDISCONNECT(m.lnSQL)
ENDIF

IF m.lnResult < 0
    AERROR(m.laErr)
    ERROR m.laErr[2]
ENDIF

IF USED(m.lcSQLAlias)
    TRY
        m.lnReturn = AFIELDS(m.taArray, m.lcSQLAlias)
    CATCH TO m.loExc
        THROW
    FINALLY
        USE IN SELECT(m.lcSQLAlias)
    ENDTRY
ENDIF

RETURN m.lnReturn
ENDFUNC
```

Answer (score 2):

Resolved this issue by setting

```
SQLSETPROP(0, "DispLogin", 3)
```

before I connected.

Comment: I'd also use OLEDB over ODBC. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839